# Why is the 0th character not getting printed when a space is printed in the cin statement?

Tags: c++, file-io, file-handling

I'm reading a line from a text file and printing each character in the line using a for loop. Why is the `0`th character of the line `p` not getting printed?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int max_length = 100; 
    char line1[max_length];
    
    freopen("input2.txt", "r", stdin);
    cin.getline(line1, max_length);
    
    for (int i = 0; line1[i] != '\0'; i++)
       cout<<line1[i]<<" "; 

    cout << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; line1[i] != '\0'; i++)
       cout<<line1[i];      

    cout << "\n";
    fclose(stdin);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Input in file:

```
pqrstuwvx
```

Output:

```
  q r s t u w v x 
 pqrstuwvx
```

However if I write the `cout` statement in this manner `cout<<line1[i];` , it gives correct output. Please explain me the reason.

Comment: Problem is not reproducible.

Comment: Add the header ```#include <fstream>```. Then add the line ```ofstream out( "input2.txt" ); for ( char c : { 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'w', 'v', 'x' } ) out << c; out.close();``` just before your ```freopen``` statement. Tell us what happens.